# Decimal place issue with Excel

Tags: excel

Does anyone know how to get rid of this issue, where if you try to reduce the number of decimals visible Excel changes the value itself.

[image]

This is causing issues in using the value further, as when we sort the values of the whole spreadsheet to 2 decimal places, the value changes.

-- update

Not able to reproduce the same on a new excel sheet. It could be some setting specific to this workbook that I am not aware of.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (which is a relief).  What's the specific formatting on that cell?

Comment: Yeah .. It's "Number", I also tried on a new excel sheet and not able to reproduce. Seems like it's an issue with this particular workbook. Could be some setting etc that I am not aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is not the default behaviour in Excel.  This loss of number precision is caused by a workbook-specific setting called `Set precision as displayed`.

The setting is shown here in the `Options -> Advanced -> When calculating this woorkbook` section:

[image: Setting for Set precision as displayed]

Turning this on for a workbook will cause precision to automatically be reduced to what is visible in the workbook.

The setting is disabled\off by default and is described in more detail [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/advanced-options-33244b32-fe79-4579-91a6-48b3be0377c4?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=191711&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).  From the docs:

> Permanently changes stored values in cells from full precision (15
> digits) to whatever format is displayed, including decimal places.